# log4j изменение название файла

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Как в log4j.xml изменять название файла, куда будут сохраняться логи, во время программы?

мой **log4j.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="myLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${logFilename}.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="myLog" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="myLog"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="myLog"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

мой **Main.class**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Main {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLog");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("logFilename", "MyLog");
        logger.info("msg1");
    }
}
```

на выходе появляется файл ".log" с текстом "msg1"

Должно было получиться "MyLog.log"

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - без переменной окружения а именно:

```
<param name="File" value="${logFilename}.log"/>
```

заменить на:

```
<param name="File" value="MyLog.log"/>
```

После чего убрать строчку:

```
System.setProperty("logFilename", "MyLog");
```

Ваш код не работает потому как ${logFilename} это как правило обращение к переменной окружения, в то время как строчка setProperty это задание системной переменной. Системная переменная (System properties) != Переменная окружения (Environment variables).

Comment: Это то да, а мне нужно, чтобы во время выполнения программы я мог изменять название файла.